# How to use minimum layout for complex design in Qt

Tags: qt

I have complex GUI design and I want minimum usage of QLayout for more readable code.
I had used QGridLayout and QBoxLayout but code is not readable.
Short version of my code please do suggest modification so that code will become more readable

```
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout   = new QVBoxLayout(this); // Main Layout 

// First GroupBox  QGroupBox
QGroupBox *GroupBox1 = new QGroupBox();
QHBoxLayout *Layout1 = new QHBoxLayout(); // Layout1 contains 3 Line edits
GroupBox1->setLayout(Layout1);

// Second Group table Group Box
QGroupBox *GroupBox2 = new QGroupBox("Second Group", this);
//   GroupBox2 contains table Widget and Buttons

QHBoxLayout *tableWrapperLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *TableWidgetLayout1  = new QVBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *TableButtonLayout1  = new QVBoxLayout();
GroupBox2->setLayout(tableWrapperLayout);

// Param Table widget
QGroupBox *GroupBox3 = new QGroupBox("Third Group", this); // Same as GroupBox3

QHBoxLayout *TableWrapperLayout1  = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *TableWidgetLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *TableButtonLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout();

GroupBox3->setLayout(TableWrapperLayout1);

QHBoxLayout *groupWrapperLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
// This is Wrapper for GroupBox2     and GroupBox3
groupWrapperLayout->addWidget(GroupBox2);
groupWrapperLayout->addWidget(GroupBox3);

// Main Layout contains GroupBox1 and groupWrapper
mainLayout->addWidget(GroupBox1);
mainLayout->addLayout(groupWrapperLayout);
```

Comment: use QtCreator and don't worry about readability of the ui class and only reference the widgets you need

Comment: Please post some code showing how "unreadable" the code is. So far your question is way too broad.

Comment: @KubaOber I have used many Layout boxes. I guess i should use GridLayout instead of Horizontal and vertical boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's so unreadable about it, but here it is with a bit less verbosity. Generally speaking you don't need to use box layouts, a grid layout can do all a box layout can do. You also don't need to set parents for widgets that are managed by layouts.

In real code you of course wouldn't be creating all the buttons/edits on the heap, but simply adding them as members of the `Widget` class and then adding them to the layouts one-by-one. I used the loops and heap allocation for brevity only.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class Widget : public QWidget {
    QGridLayout m_layout;
    QGroupBox m_group1;
    QGridLayout m_group1Layout;
    QGroupBox m_group2;
    QGridLayout m_group2Layout;
    QGroupBox m_group3;
    QGridLayout m_group3Layout;
public:
    Widget(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent),
        m_layout(this),
        m_group1("First Group"),
        m_group1Layout(&m_group1),
        m_group2("Second Group"),
        m_group2Layout(&m_group2),
        m_group3("Third Group"),
        m_group3Layout(&m_group3)
    {
        m_layout.addWidget(&m_group1, 0, 0, 1, 2);
        m_layout.addWidget(&m_group2, 1, 0);
        m_layout.addWidget(&m_group3, 1, 1);

        // Line edits in group 1
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
            m_group1Layout.addWidget(new QLineEdit, 0, i);

        // Table and buttons in group 2
        m_group2Layout.addWidget(new QTableWidget, 0, 0, 4, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++ i)
            m_group2Layout.addWidget(new QPushButton(QString::number(i)), i, 1);

        // Table and buttons in group 3
        m_group3Layout.addWidget(new QTableWidget, 0, 0, 4, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++ i)
            m_group3Layout.addWidget(new QPushButton(QString::number(i)), i, 1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ! But i didn't understand this statement "You don't need to set parents for widgets that are managed by layouts" can you please explain me . Thank you once again..

Comment: @D'JayPatil Instead of `new QGroupBox("Second Group", this)` simply do `new QGroupBox("Second Group")`. The `this` parent is unnecessary for widgets that will be managed by layouts.

Comment: Okay I got it . Thank you for your valuable suggestion and explanation.